# MVC tricky issue with .js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In MVC there are 2 view say:

```
  View-A contains A.js which further contains function A()

  View-B contains B.js which further contains function B()
```

Now I want to call `function A()` from `View-B's B.js` file

What i can`t do :-

```
     #1 I can`t embed A.js into View-B
     #2 I can`t embed A.js into _Layout.cshtml
```

If this is possible then pls tell me how?

Comment: why not simply create a new js file including a() and b() and embed this file in the view?

Comment: Why can't you include A.js in view B?  You're going to need to deliver that JavaScript code to the client if you want the client to be able to use it.

Comment: If you don't load a function you can't use it. If you 'can't' load a function then the Model View Controller is ... now .... controlling ... you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `getScript` in view B

```
$.getScript('jsfile.js',function(){
  //call function A 
});
```